# How to display on sale products with discound >2%

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

In woocomerce i have a lot of products that have the same price in both regular price and on sale price.

I want to display only the products that have a discount.

I tried to display the on sale products with the woocomerce shortcode [products on_sale="true" limit="12" paginate="true" columns="3" visibility="visible"].

The problem is that displays all products with on sale price, even if its the same price.

So i want to display only the products with discount > 1%.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', function() {
    global $product; 
    $sale = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true);
    $regular = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);

    if ( isset($sale) && $sale < $regular ) {
        echo '<span class="onsale soldout">Sale!</span>';
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, with this code it only displays the label over the product.

I want to filter the products with discount more than 1% and display only these.

The label is already on.